# Dates range overlapping with infinite intervals

Tags: sql, oracle, algorithm, plsql

I have a function in `Oracle` that checks if two dates overlap each other. There is no problem with it, because `[a, b]` overlaps with `[x, y]` if `b > x and a < y`. Works fine for defined `start/end date 1` and `start/end date 2`. But now I want to modify it. If any of given dates is `NULL` it should be treated as `+-infinite`.

It's a code:

```
  FUNCTION OVERLAP(p_START_DATE_1 DATE, p_END_DATE_1 DATE,
   p_START_DATE_2 DATE, p_END_DATE_2 DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

   lv_RESULT VARCHAR2(1);
  BEGIN 
       lv_RESULT := 'N';      

       IF (p_START_DATE_1 <= p_END_DATE_2 AND p_END_DATE_1 >= p_START_DATE_2) THEN
         lv_RESULT := 'Y';
       END IF;

       RETURN lv_RESULT;
  END OVERLAP;
```

**For instance:** Suppose that `p_START_DATE_1` is `NULL`. In this case that code:

```
SELECT MY_PACKAGE_SQL.OVERLAP(
       NULL,
       TO_DATE('01/12/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
       TO_DATE('01/02/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
       TO_DATE('01/05/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
FROM DUAL;
```

... should return `Y`, because first date range is `(-infinite, 01/12/2014]` and it overlaps with `[01/02/2012, 01/05/2012]`.

Now my problem... I know I can use additional `"IFs"` to check `NULLs`. But I wonder if it's any other solution to make it faster in `Oracle's PL\SQL` language? It's like `do it in smarter way challenge` in my team `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method to implement this:

```
   IF (coalesce(p_START_DATE_1, p_end_date_2, sysdate) <= coalesce(p_END_DATE_2, p_START_DATE_1, sysdate) AND
       coalesce(p_END_DATE_1, p_START_DATE_2, sysdate) >= coalesce(p_START_DATE_2, p_END_DATE_1, sysdate) THEN
```

The idea is to replace the `NULL` values with values that will satisfy each condition.  If both are `NULL`, then use `sysdate`.

Comment: Could you tell me if it is possible to do the same for `contains` function?

Comment: @Nickon . . . Isn't `contains()` used for string searches?  I don't see how that function would apply.

Comment: I mean my own function `CONTAINS(start1 date, end1 date, start2 date, end2 date)` - it should check if `[start1, end1]` contains `[start2, end2]`. Can it be done using `coalesce()`?

Answer (score 2):

```
if nvl(p_START_DATE_1<=p_END_DATE_2 and p_START_DATE_2<=p_END_DATE_1, true) then
```

---

**EDIT :**
To check if [start1, end1] contains [start2, end2]:

```
if nvl(start1 <= nvl(start2,start1 - 1) and end1 >= nvl(end2,end1 + 1),true) then
```